# Visual Studio Code - error after rename file from lower case to upper case

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

After I rename my file name (lower case to upper case) in VS Code, example card.cs to Card.cs, I got this error: The type of namespace could not be found are you missing a using directive or an assembly

How should I fix this issue?

Secondly, should I rename it at VS code locally, then push to my Git or should I rename it at Git and then pull it from Git?

Comment: Where does the error show?

Comment: in visual studio code under "Problems" tab.

Comment: example, this line now got error: private List<Card> cards;

Comment: Search for lowercase `card` because there are some places where it is still not changed to uppercase.

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+B` build your code again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Somehow after restart my VS Code, the error no more already. Solution is to rename in VS Code using 'rename' function and if file name is different I rename it using Git command

Answer (score 4):

It also happens to me when changing uppercase to lowercase or vice versa. If it gets stuck like this and VS Code still requires the old name, it helps me to change the name to something else entirely and then rename it to what I want.

Comment: This one + the one with 'restart VSC' should be the accepted answers.

Comment: for me not enough to only restart vscode BUT renaming to something else entirely and then rename it perfectly worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I had same issue, renamed a class lower case to uppercase by clicking Rename inside VS Code (Mac). Terminal shows a file name mismatch error displaying lower case name. Git Desktop showed lower case name. VS Code shows new name in files panel. My solution: Disable git extensions, delete the classes from my org, shut down git desktop and vs code. Restart vs code. Trying again it failed but only when I use cmd-p to deploy source for the visible window. If I right click on the filename in the files panel and deploy from there, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me when I renamed from `PascalCase` case to `snake_case`, but for some reason the IntelliSense in VS Code was still adding imports at the top of the file with the old name.

So make sure all imports of the old name have been changed to their new case. And if you want to stop code completion adding the old case in the import declarations then restart VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Had lower case, changed to Uppercase. VSCode Restart worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Contrary to my assumption that I thought the problem was from TypeScript, Node.js, VS Code or the installed packages or  VS Code extensions; the problem was from Git. To solve this problem, I changed the file name to a temporary name and also changed the places where it was used and then pushed the changes with git push. Then I changed the file name to the original name that I wanted and repeated the same path again and pushed the changes with git push and the error message was resolved.